# cvCalibrateCamera2 - how to properly define rotation matrix?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, rotational-matrices

I try to use cvCalibrateCamera2, but I get error that rotation matrix is not properly defined:

> ...calibration.cpp:1495: error: (-5) the output array of rotation vectors must be 3-channel 1xn or nx1 array or 1-channel nx3 or nx9 array, where n is the number of views

I have already tried all possibilities from that info but I still get this error.

My code:

```
CvMat *object_points = cvCreateMat((int)pp.object_points.size(), 1, CV_32FC3);
CvMat *image_points = cvCreateMat((int)pp.image_points.size(), 1, CV_32FC2);
const CvMat point_counts = cvMat((int)pp.point_counts.size(), 1, CV_32SC1, &pp.point_counts[0]);

for (size_t i=0; i<pp.object_points.size(); i++) 
{
  object_points->data.fl[i*3+0] = (float)pp.object_points[i].x;
  object_points->data.fl[i*3+1] = (float)pp.object_points[i].y;
  object_points->data.fl[i*3+2] = (float)pp.object_points[i].z;
  image_points->data.fl[i*2+0]  = (float)pp.image_points[i].x;
  image_points->data.fl[i*2+1]  = (float)pp.image_points[i].y;
}

CvMat* tempR = cvCreateMat(1, 3, CV_32F);

cvCalibrateCamera2(object_points, image_points, &point_counts,
                   cvSize(pp.width, pp.height), camera->m_calib_K,
                   camera->m_calib_D, tempR, &tempData->m_calib_T,
                   CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS)

// camera->calib_T is defined as:
// double m_calib_T_data[3];
// cvMat(3, 1, CV_64F, camera->m_calib_T_data);
```

I thought that rotation matrix used in cvCalibrateCamera2 should be 1x3 (then I want to use Rodrigues function to get 3x3 matrix) but it doesn't work as any other combination mentioned in error.

Any ideas?

And I use opencv 2.4.0 (maybe there is bug in that method, but for some reasons I can't use later version of opencv)

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement is clear. I am not confident with C# but I know it requires a strong initialization. 
The problem in line

```
CvMat* tempR = cvCreateMat(1, 3, CV_32F);
```

is that `tempR` should have a line 1x3 for every N objects point you use. In this sense, the statement becomes clear

> ...calibration.cpp:1495: error: (-5) the output array of rotation
>   vectors must be 3-channel 1xn or nx1 array or 1-channel nx3 or nx9
>   array, where n is the number of views

You must create a tempR like that (more or less, I do not know how to calculate `N` in C#)

```
CvMat* tempR = cvCreateMat(N, 3, CV_32F);
```

Try to extract N from dimensions of object.point.size. If it does not work, try image.point.size

Comment: First of all, it's c++. Why do you think this is c#? Second, how to get 3x3 camera rotation matrix and 1x3 translation vector if I have n = 50 views, so after using cvCalibrateCamera2 I get 50x3 matrix (rotation matrix) and 50x3 translation matrix?

Comment: @never_ever: yes. Assuming that you are calibrating a mono-camera in the classic way with a checkerboard (it does not seem stereo calibration to me, since you are not using stereocalibrate() function or something like that) the only rotation-translation object that you can obtain are the relative transformation from the image plane to the (many) checkerboard plane(s) (or vice versa). Did you expected something different? (About C++ it is my mistake, sorry. I started to use openCV with python)